# Crystal Report Gauge On Change of Date Period

Tags: crystal-reports, charts, gauge

I have a Crystal Report where I am using the 'gauge' chart to display On Time delivery for a business.  The Gauge requires an "On Change Of", but I ahve two seperate values I want to display on the same gauge, one for overall and one for the last week.  I can do this, by creating a null formula and setting the OnChange of to that, but then the needles are the same color.  Any thoughts on how I can get one needle for overall and one needle for last week?

My Table is just a list of Manufacutring Orders with Due Dates and Completion Dates.  I use a formula to decide if the order was on time, if it was I print the Order Number.  Then I use a summary field with a distinct count of order numbers to determinie the total number on time orders.  This divide by the total distinct order counts and then I get a percentage for OTD...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this one deserves some more explanation.  For each detail, which was essentially a list of sales orders, I had a date requested and a date completed.  From those two fields I calculated a third field that returned either "On Time", "Late", or "3 Day Window" and I wanted to display a gauge chart of all records On Time.... Our OTD %

In addition to this I wanted to display the weekly numbers versus the numbers prior to that week.  To do this I created a fourth column that returned either "This Week" or "Historical".  I could now do a Multiple gauge type chart for each record with an on change of OTD State and Weeklyorhistorical.  This produces side by side gauges labeled correctly with historical and weekly OTD.